# Coroutine and function interface in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public suspend inline operator fun  CoroutineDispatcher.invoke(noinline block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T) defined in kotlinx.coroutines
I get this after changing type of ColorFunc who is simple fun interface

```
fun interface InterfaceColor{
    fun setColor(x: Float): Color
}
```

[ColorFunc changed from (Float)->Color to InterfaceColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRYs6.png)

Tryed parse but nothing left

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple : `fun interface` does not mean `invokable`.

When you use a function definition like `(Float) -> Color`, you require an `invokable` object whose function can be called with `(args)`. In your example, this is `colorFunc(res)`.

But, fun interfaces do not imply `Invokable`. It means that to trigger the interface function, you need to call it by name. In your example, you need to *explicitely* call `setColor(x: Float` on your object. You must change your call from `colorFunc(res)` to `colorFunc.setColor(res)`.

So, why fun interfaces are not invokable ? I think this is to avoid confusion. Nothing prevents an object to inherit multiple interfaces, and implying that a fun interface is invokable might cause ambiguity when an object contains multiple behavior.